# how to read service configuration (.cscfg) of a cloud service created on RM subscription

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, cscfg

I have a cloud service (classic) created on RM subscription. I need to read its service config (.cscfg), update the config and redrploy it back to the cloud service.

I did it using get-azuredeploy command on Classic, but this command doesnt work on RM subscription.

does anyone know how to get service config from RM subscription?

Comment: What do you mean with RM subscription? I guess you want to use only RM related PowerShell cmdlets?`

Comment: Resource Manager  subscription or non-classic subscription, you cant use classic commands on this subscription, like Select-Azuresubscription, instead you have to to us RM command to select the subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the command below, the `$slot.Properties.configuration` should be that.

```
$slot = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -ResourceType Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/slots -ResourceName "xxxxx" -ApiVersion 2016-04-01
$slot.Properties.configuration
```